# Ruby on Rails: Facing problems while trying to create instance variable of another controller in ApplicationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to know how to call a method of another controller in `ApplicationController`, when this other controller is derived from `ApplicationController`.

Answer (score 1):

`ApplicationController` is the parent of all the controller classes, and you can't call a method of child class in it. Simply, `ApplicationController` won't know how to access that method.

Most of the time, we put methods in `ApplicationController` class, so that all the other classes could use those methods if need be, but your case is very different. So, **NO**, you can't call a method of child controller in `ApplicationController`.

It has nothing to do with Rails. It'd simply be the violation of Object Oriented principles.